# Firebase Cloud Functions - serving multiple users at once

Tags: axios, google-cloud-functions, fs

I'm creating a Firebase function that grabs images from a webpage that the user specifies. My current implementation downloads the images using axios and saves them using fs to the local function project directory. I have only been able to test the function locally, so I'm not sure how it will work in production.

Since I have the files saved locally, what happens if multiple users call the function at the same time with different webpages? Will the files overwrite each other?

Thanks

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post. Since the first one is about Google Cloud Functions infrastructure, I answered it below. But the second one is more about your specific use-case, so others may be better suited to answer it. I recommend posting that second question again in a new post.

Comment: Regarding your second question. The possibility of files overwriting each other will strictly depend on your code. You'll need to write a function that is idempotent in the sense that you need to guarantee that each file downloaded to the function's local directory has a different name. You'd also need to be careful with OOM errors, as the files you download will take RAM space assigned to your function. I recommend you to go through the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) to get further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I have the files saved locally, what happens if multiple users call the function at the same time with different webpages? Will the files overwrite each other?

Parallel invocations will run on separate instances. Cloud Functions automatically creates as many instances as needed, and scales back down when load decreases.